# Call an Intent on click of Pause button Pressed while video playing in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a problem that I want to call a User Defined function on `Pause Button` Pressed while playing a `video file` in our App, How can I do that? Please suggest me for right result.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

```
VideoView v=new VideoView(this);
```

Take one Button to pause Video and then call

```
   v.pause();
```

now after this you can do anything